# .getElementById('').getElementById('').style doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('menu').getElementById('line1').style.opacity = "0";
```

**HTML**

```
<a href = "#"><div id = "menu" onclick="menu()">
            <div id = "line1">1</div>
            <div id = "line2">1</div>
            <div id = "line3">1</div>
        </div></a>
```

So I am trying to make the first line disappear, but it doesn't run for some reason. **Do i have something wrong with my syntax?** The reason I have the additional .getElementById('menu') is because I have div id = "menuClose" to return back to the original. Unless there is another way?

Comment: `getElementById()` is a method on the `document` object only. Elements (`div`, etc.) don't have this method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you selecting menu first? You can select the line directly since it's identified by an id:

```
document.getElementById('line1').style.opacity = "0";
```

[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/52f2g/).

If you want to change all the div contained in another div (in your case all the divs contained in the div with `id="menu"`), use `document.getElementById('menu').childNodes` and then iterate as shown [on this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780443/how-to-select-all-children-of-an-element-with-javascript-and-change-css-property)

Comment: I have another div called menuClose that looks exactly the same and it will hide all of these and show itself? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: @skarchmit use classes and `document.getElementsByClassName` for that

Comment: You can select the parent and then use [childNodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381296/best-way-to-get-child-nodes), but at this point you have to question your markup since ids must be unique, i.e. there isn't another div with id line1.

Comment: And make sure the elements within `menuClose` have different IDs than those in `menu`. IDs *must* be unique within the document.

Comment: @EndeNeu 

document.getElementById('line1').style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(45deg) translate3d(10px,10px,0)";
  document.getElementById('line2').style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(-45deg) translate3d(10,-10px,0)";
  document.getElementById('line3').style.WebkitTransform = "rotate(45deg) translate3d(10,-10px,0)";

When I do this, it only affects the first one, but when its opacity it works fine.

Comment: As I said, if your div has an id and you use `getElementById` you select **only** that element, that means that whathever function you apply later will be applied only to that element you specifically selected. If you want to apply the changes to all the rows, select the div that contains all the div you want to change (in your case the div with id menu) and then iterate the element and apply the properties, [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9780443/how-to-select-all-children-of-an-element-with-javascript-and-change-css-property) shows how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

```
document.getElementById('line1').style.opacity = "0";
```

This is all you need to do. line1 is an id, so it can be retrieved using getElementById without having to access the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

please try

```
document.getElementById('line1').style.display='none';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple as you are selecting menu first, But you may try this method

```
document.getElementById('line1').style.display='none';
```

May this helps,