# Javascript select an ID by its name

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an option select that is supposed to change the div content by matching the name of the ID in my HTML (in `monthchosen`) with the value that has been chosen by the user.

The only problem I'm having is that I do not know how to check the option value against the div id using plain javascript. The final part `months[i].id.includes(monthchosen)` is incorrect, though hopefully gets across what I am trying to accomplish. I have content under div ids named after the option select `(ie: <div id="oct2016">)` that I would like to show when the names correspond.

My example uses React, though a solution in pure JS might suffice.

**My JavaScript:**

```
updatedate:function(){
    var months = document.getElementsByClassName('month');
    var monthchosen = this.refs.datechosen;
    for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i++){
        months[i].style.display = 'none';
        months[i].id.includes(monthchosen).style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

**My HTML**

```
    <select ref="datechosen" id="datechosen" onChange={this.updatedate}>
        <option value="nov2016">November 2016</option>
        <option value="oct2016">October 2016</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: what is an error?will you please elaborate it more

Comment: the error is `cannot set display of undefined`. this is because the includes returns to me a boolean, not an editable property.

Comment: A react component really shouldn't be running global queries `var months = document.getElementsByClassName('month');` makes your component not be reusable

Comment: Have the function updatedate called on change like you have it, but get the selected value by using document.getElementById("datechosen").value;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to search w3schools for various simple but clutch JavaScript syntax.  I ask you to forgive me because I learned jQuery first so I do not know all of the vanilla equivalents off hand.  JavaScript has default methods to query what was selected in a `<selection>` element.  Also the following StackOverflow post got me like 95% of the way there: [How to select all children of an element with javascript and change CSS property?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9780508/5076162)

What happens is we capture the value attribute in a variable immediately when the function is invoked.  Then, we loop through again and use the JavaScript ternary method to quickly compare what should be hidden and what should be displayed.

**HTML:**

```
<select ref="datechosen" id="datechosen" onChange=updatedate()>
    <option value="dec2016">December 2016</option>
    <option value="nov2016">November 2016</option>
    <option value="oct2016">October 2016</option>
</select>
<div id='dec2016' class='month'>
    DEC
</div>
<div id='oct2016' class='month'>
    OCT
</div>
<div id='nov2016' class='month'>
    NOV
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
    function updatedate() {
        var months = document.getElementsByClassName('month');
        var whichIsSelected = '';

        var nodes = document.getElementById('datechosen').childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            if (nodes[i].selected) {
                whichIsSelected = nodes[i].value;
            }
        }
        for (var x = 0; x < months.length; x++) {
            months[x].style.display = (months[x].id === whichIsSelected) ? 'block' : 'none';
        }

        console.log(whichIsSelected);
    }

</script>
```

```js
    function updatedate() {
        var months = document.getElementsByClassName('month');
        var whichIsSelected = '';
        //var monthchosen = this.attr.ref;

        var nodes = document.getElementById('datechosen').childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            if (nodes[i].selected) {
                //whichIsSelected.push(nodes[i].value);
                whichIsSelected = nodes[i].value;
            }
        }
        for (var x = 0; x < months.length; x++) {
            months[x].style.display = (months[x].id === whichIsSelected) ? 'block' : 'none';
        }


        console.log(whichIsSelected);
    }
```

```html
<select ref="datechosen" id="datechosen" onChange=updatedate()>
    <option value="dec2016">December 2016</option>
    <option value="nov2016">November 2016</option>
    <option value="oct2016">October 2016</option>
</select>
<div id='dec2016' class='month'>
    DEC
</div>
<div id='oct2016' class='month'>
    OCT
</div>
<div id='nov2016' class='month'>
    NOV
</div>
```